# Magento 2 how to get product name and qty in mini cart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

Magento 2 how to get product name and its qty in mini cart when we add to mini cart

Comment: By default, Magento minicart shows product name and quantity.

Comment: I need to get that details in .phtml file

Comment: What is your requirement? Minicart is created using ui components.

Comment: I need to get product details in phtml file when they added to minicart....

Comment: So where do you need that data? you can create default.html file under Magento_Checkout->web->template->minicart->item, and edit the default layout of mini cart, like add sku of products and ... . But where do you want to show that data?

Comment: Data should be show in related product detail page...

Comment: Please check my answer. You can add this code in your block and get details in your phtml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code :

**Factory Method :**

```
protected $_cart;
public function __construct(
    ..................................
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    ..................................
) {
    ..................................
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    ..................................
}


public function yourfunction()
{
    $cartProductList = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach($cartProductList as $item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";            
      }
}
```

**Object Manager Method :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$cartProductList = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($cartProductList as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";
}
```

It will helpful for you.

Comment: I have .phtml file but above code its not working Rohan Hapani

Comment: Can you please post your error or log?

Comment: If you want to get data direct in phtml file then you need to get data by object manager. You want to get direct in phtml?

Comment: Yeah i need data directly in phtml file Rohan Hapani

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83472/discussion-between-trilok-kumar-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: How can i get same values in related products  @Rohan Hapani..

Comment: check in chat room