# Change price at "checkout_cart_update_items_after"

Tags: magento2, event-observer, price

I have some rules that change the price of product 'Z' if
the quantity of products 'X' is 'Y' In the cart, how can I check the quantity of a product in the cart and change the price of that product using the `checkout_cart_update_items_after` event, because I need this checked after clicking the update button or whenever I change the cart also helps.

more specifically what I need to know is how to change the **price** and get the **quantity** with this event
Any help is welcome!

Magento 2.3.3
Xampp
Win 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using the "checkout_cart_save_after" event

```
<?php

namespace ModWay\mod\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class ProductCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Below is the method that will fire whenever the event runs!
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        $cart = $observer->getData('cart');
        $quote = $cart->getData('quote');
        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

        foreach($items as $item)
        {

            if($item->getSku()=='MSH09-32-Black'){
                $item->setCustomPrice(8);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice(8);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                $item->save();
            }

        }
        $quote->save();
       // $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you hints and idea. You have to done it by your self :)

Make an observer. check product qty whenever this event fired. then update the price

These two links will help you :)

[How To Get Product QTY](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243161/magento-2-how-to-get-product-name-and-qty-in-mini-cart)

[Update Product price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181867/change-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento2)

Try to do it by yourself so you can learn something :)
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am trying to do yes, I already have a way to get the quantity and price and apply the rules I need, I can change the price that displayed in the catalog using a Plugin intercepting the getPrice magento but I can not avoid saving the price I need when any cart change happens, every cart change I need to read the information and apply the rules if I need to but I don't know how to save after some change event, the second link you sent me might not help me using an event For "cart_product_add_after", I need to change the cart price after any changes to it.